# Javascript variable failing to pass into JSP function.

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the following code below from a JSP page. This is from a javascript.

```
$('area').on('mouseover', function() {
    var territory = $(this).attr('name');
    var owner;
    if(territory != null)
    {
        owner = <% game.getTerritory( request.getParameter("territory")).getOwner().getName() ; %>;
    }
    $('#selection').html0(territory + "\n");
});
```

For some reason I'm getting a null pointer exception on the owner = Line, I'm guessing this is from the request.getParameter. I'm not exactly sure what I'm getting wrong though.  I'm somewhat new to this, and I'm wondering if I'm going the wrong way about this.

Thanks

Comment: is territory variable is added in this request?

Comment: yeah. I'm adding the territory js variable

Comment: js variables cannot be added in the request. request variables are something you added from your controller code.

Comment: Then is there any way to get the JS territory into the game.getTerritory param?